# exited with non-zero status

Tags: c

I am new in programming and try to learn by own ,i have an error in my code,i don't understand it's a syntax error or i've done smth wrong.I used 3 equations with it's condition and made it in for isntruction,while,do-while,if-else,with switch.After i introduce variable a it show me  an error "exited with non-zero status".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    float a,x,b;
    float L;
    int m;

    printf("Enter variables a,x,b:");
    scanf("%f%f%f,&a,&x,&b");
    printf("For using for instruction (enter 1)");
    printf("For using while instruction (enter 2)");
    printf("For using do-while instruction (enter 3)");
    printf("For using ef instruction (enter 4)");
    scanf("%d,&m");
    switch(m){
        case 1:
            for (x=0;x<1.2;x++)
            {
                L=2*cos(x-(3.14/6));
            }
            for (x=0;x>= 1.2 && x<=3.9;x++)
            {
                L=x*x/(a+cos(powf((x+b),3)));
            }
            for (x=0;x>3.9;x++)
            {
                L=fabs(x/2*a)+powf(sin(x+1),2);
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            while (x<1.2)
            {
                 L=2*cos(x-(3.14/6));
            }
            while (x>= 1.2 && x<=3.9)
            {
                 L=x*x/(a+cos(powf((x+b),3)));
            }
            while (x>3.9)
            {
                 L=fabs(x/2*a)+powf(sin(x+1),2);
            }
            break;
       case 3:
            do 
            {
                L=2*cos(x-(3.14/6));
            }
            while (x<1.2);
            do 
            {
                L=x*x/(a+cos(powf((x+b),3)));
            }
            while (x>= 1.2 && x<=3.9);
            do
            {
                L=fabs(x/2*a)+powf(sin(x+1),2);
            }
            while (x>3.9);
            break;
       case 4:
           if (x<1.2)
           {
               L=2*cos(x-(3.14/6));
           }
           else
           {
               printf("First statement is false");
           }
           if(x>= 1.2 && x<=3.9)
           {
               L=x*x/(a+cos(powf((x+b),3)));
           }
           else
           {
               printf("Second statement is false");
           }
           if(x>3.9)
           {
               L=fabs(x/2*a)+powf(sin(x+1),2);
           }
           else
           {
               printf("Third statement is false");
           }
           break;
       default:
           printf("\nNo right choices\n");
   }
   printf("Your answer is: L = %.3f,L");
}
```

Comment: Does the execution reach the end?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: @TomKarzes Not correct. See 5.1.2.2.3 Program termination, paragraph 1 of the C Standard.  "... reaching the `}` that terminates the `main` function returns a value of 0."  (This does assume the compiler in use is C99 (or later) compliant...)

Comment: As @Neo implies, you're likely getting an abnormal termination, possibly from a divide-by-zero error.  Step through your code with a debugger.  You can also help by flushing `stdout` after every all to `printf()`: `fflush( stdout );`, IIRC.  Aside:  any code is a ***LOT*** easier to understand if your indentation style is consistent - putting some on separate lines, and then some stuffed on one line between `{` and `}` is confusing.

Comment: Your `scanf`s don't compile for me - the ending double-quote should be before the first comma.

Comment: What did you insert to make it fail? I changed the `scanf`s as I wrote and also replaced them with `scanf_s` because VS didn't like them and it works fine.

Comment: What's your platform and compiler version?

Comment: I use repl.it .

Comment: @VadimDoga that may be worth mentioning in the question. What is you input?

Comment: @VadimDoga see answers dealing with `scanf` below. I suggest you use a real development environnment running on your computer instead of an online compiler.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that your `scanf` arguments are not formatted correctly.

Instead of `scanf("%f%f%f,&a,&x,&b");` use `scanf("%f%f%f",&a,&x,&b);`. Same in the second `scanf`.

The variables addresses are parameters, not part of the string.

When you call it, `scanf` finds the first `%f` but it doesn't have any address to put the value into. Or more accuratly, it finds the value it needs from garbage (read about the stack and dynamic number of arguments), because you didn't insert it.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%f%f%f,&a,&x,&b")`; should be like this `scanf("%f%f%f",&a,&x,&b);`. Please correct where ever you used scanf. Your code is not taking input from user due to wrong syntax. I have compiled and tried it is runnig correctly. Please change scanf syntax every where.

1. `scanf("%f%f%f,&a,&x,&b")` to `scanf("%f%f%f",&a,&x,&b)`
2. `scanf("%d,&m");` to `scanf("%d",&m);`
3. `printf("Your answer is: L = %.3f,L");` to `printf("Your answer is: L = %.3f",L);`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the return 0; Statement at the end of the main function. Since c main function is **int** main ()

Comment: No.  Per **5.1.2.2.3 Program termination**, paragraph 1 of [the C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):  "... reaching  the
`}`
that  terminates  the
`main`
function  returns  a  value  of  0."

Comment: @AndrewHenle AFAIK some old implementations may not implicitly return 0.

Comment: That's not the problem here. Delete the answer.